# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Trying to do a recordset, I just want one column of data, but this code is giving me an error.. I'm an ASP.NET newb, can anyone help?:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name
>   'CustomerName'.

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DB.GetDBConn()))
 {
  con.Open();
  using (IDataReader dr = DB.GetRS("select CustomerName from Customer where CustomerID=" + Customer.CustomerID, con))
   {
       string CustomerName = "CustomerName";                    
   }
 }

 String EncCustomerName = Encrypt(CustomerName.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", ""),"1");
```

Question #2:  How do I bind the database content to the CustomerName string? It seems like its only returning "CustomerName" as the value for CustomerName string.. I would like it to return the database data for CustomerName string..  Help?

Suggested to use a ExecuteScalar, so i modified the request to this

```
   using (var con = new SqlConnection(DB.GetDBConn()))
   using (var cmdContrib = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer WHERE   CustomerID=" + ThisCustomer.CustomerID, con))

   {

        con.Open();
        string CustomerName = cmdContrib.ExecuteScalar();
   }
```

And i Get this error:
"string CustomerName = cmdCust.ExecuteScalar();"

CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Try running the query "select CustomerName from Customer" directly in Management Studio.  I bet you'll find some kind of spelling error (Sincerely not insulting your intelligence, that kind of stuff happens).

Comment: you're right, i was not thinking right.  But now it wont give me the dynamic data.. it returns "CustomerName" as the value for the CustomerName variable, but i want the data from the database, why is it not returning the dynamic data?

Comment: You're explicitly setting `CustomerName` to "CustomerName".  You need to access the actual value of the CustomerName column from `dr` (something like `string CustomerName = dr["CustomerName"];`)

Comment: @jadarnel27: Okay i did that, and it says.... ERROR CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: `string CustomerName = dr["CustomerName"].ToString();`  I'm on the East Coast (US) and it's 3 AM.  I'm going to sleep =)  good luck!

Comment: New Error:  CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: That line will most likely fail as the default position for the reader is before any records.  The reader has to be advanced by the `Read()` method before you can pull values out.  SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar would be a better option in this case, IMO.

Comment: @Wilkins - check my answer for two different ways you may get this to work.

Comment: @Wilkins - look at my example again.  You forgot the `Convert.ToString()` around `cmdContrib.ExecuteScalar()` part.  ExecuteScalar returns an object - you have to convert it to the proper type (string, in this case).  So you should have `CustomerGUID = Convert.ToString(cmdContrib.ExecuteScalar());`.  Also note that you should declare the CustomerGUID string outside of your using block, otherwise you won't be able to access it outside of those blocks.

Comment: First: Two questions here, it's fragmentted beyond belief.  Second: The op replies with "it doesn't work", not enough detail to be usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question:

```
// Set it here so you can access it outside the scope of the using statement
string CustomerName = "";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DB.GetDBConn()))
{
    con.Open();
    using (IDataReader dr = DB.GetRS("select CustomerName from Customer where CustomerID=" + Customer.CustomerID, con))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
            CustomerName = dr["CustomerName"].ToString();
        }                    
    }
 }
```

If you're sure you'll only get one CustomerName result, using a DataReader is a bit of an overkill.

**SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Example**

```
string CustomerName = "";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DB.GetDBConn()))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = " + Customer.CustomerID, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    con.Open();

    CustomerName = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

}
```

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

**Additional Info**

ExecuteScalar returns an object, so you'll need to convert the returned value to the proper type (in this case, string).

Also, you should declare your CustomerName value outside of the using blocks (as I did in my example) - otherwise it will be scoped to the using blocks and not available outside of them.

Comment: what should i use instead, if all i need is one result?

Comment: I'm not sure what `DB` is, but you could use ADO.NET and the `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` method.  Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: i found an example,thank you.. but its still giving me the same error.. i will post the new code

Answer (score 0):

It means that either `CustomerName` or `CustomerID` is not a valid column within your database. Check your table again.

Comment: It is a valid column name, thats the thing.

Comment: @Wilkins Is there any blank in these name?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are trying to connect correct database.
2. See CustomerName column should be in Customer table. check spelling also

Comment: Add your schema name like dbo.customer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `select * from customer where ...` and put a breakpoint on your using datareader statement. Then use quick-watch on the datareader object to investigate the columns exposed in the recordset.

Or you could run the select statement on your db of choice to ensure that the column name is the same.

I agree with Madhur above, your column name is not spelled correctly. Or you are not connecting to the correct db.

Hope this helps

Comment: How do I bind the database content to the CustomerName string? It seems like its only returning "CustomerName" as the value for CustomerName string.. I would like it to return the database data for CustomerName string

Comment: Please refer to jadarnel27's comment above. You need to change your string assignment for customer name. Please use string customername = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("CustomerName")); or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, debug and check the value of:

```
DB.GetDBConn()
```

You will verify that you are going to the same in Studio as you are in the program.

I think it is the spelling somewhere between the db and your code.

Once you get past the error, you need to fix this:

```
{
       string CustomerName = "CustomerName";                    
   }
```

You are not accessing the reader, try some kind of tutorial for that stuff.

Comment: I don't really use readers, but I'm guessing dr["CustomerName"] will give you a result - what do you want to do with it?